# Cookie returns undefined value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to make a cookie to remember a radius that a user can choose. The problem is that the cookie works, but the value of the cookie is undefined. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

The function "opslaan" is linked with a button on the HTML page.

```
function opslaan()
{
    createCookie('radius',document.getElementById("range").value,8);
    alert("opgeslagen");
}

function readCookie(name)
{
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ')
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = ";expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else
        var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires +";path=/";
}
```

This is the button and the range field where it need to get the value out:

```
<fieldset class="one-third column">
    <label for="">Radius van de kaart (km)</label>
    <input type="range"
           min="5"
           max="20"
           value="5"
           step="5"
           onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">5</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showValue(newValue)
        {
            document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
        }
    </script>
</fieldset>
<script>
    alert(readCookie('radius'));
</script>

<div class="one-third column">
    <a class="full-width button margin-top25"
       href="home.html" 
       onclick="opslaan()">
        Opslaan
    </a>
</div>
```

It seems to be working without the range field and button.

Comment: It seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ddus4/2/

Comment: i added my code of the button and range field perhaps its in that part where i made some mistake

Comment: `document.getElementById("range").value` is going to return undefined. Which is your problem here. Try using `document.getElementById("range").innerHTML `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `range` is a `span` not an input element, so you need to use `innerHTML` property to read the contents of that element instead of using `value`.

use

```
document.getElementById("range").innerHTML
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("range").value
```

Ex:

```
function opslaan()
{
    createCookie('radius',document.getElementById("range").innerHTML,8);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ddus4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("range").value` is going to return undefined. Which is your problem here. Try using `document.getElementById("range").innerHTML`